# Floodfill algorithm with seed area (instead of seed point)

Tags: opencv, flood-fill

in the standard openCV floodfill algorithm you should specify a seed point.

Is there an easy way to specify a starting area (so multiple seeding point)? Or do I really have to loop over every point in that area :(

Thx!!

Comment: What do you mean "every point in that area"?! You give a seed point in the area and the whole are will be filled...

Comment: Would be useful for you to understand how floodfill works. Seed area has no meaning in this context